# How I can preserve the color of the output of command when being called from c++?

Tags: c++

I have this function that runs a command, while the command is running it will store the standard output into a variable, after it finishes it will print into the screen the result and return the code

```
int exec(const string &command) {
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen((command + " 2>&1").c_str(), "r"), pclose);
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    if (!result.empty()) {
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
    return pclose(pipe.get());
}
```

The only problem I have is that the output color of the command gets lost, could be possible to keep it?

Comment: The program may know that it is not outputing to a terminal, thus it outputs w/o coloring.

Comment: how does the program know if it's outputing to a terminal then? can I make it believe it's doing that?

Comment: You question is strange. How can we help you if we don't know the command and the OS.

Comment: sorry I didn't explained well, I'm running this function on linux, mac and windows. For the command I'm using clang, so if I pass the flag -fcolor-diagnostics then I get the color. 

that works for now but I'm going to need this exec function to be generic, so I want to run the command in a way that always thinks that is running in a terminal so I get the color. 

I know there is an env varaible called TERM and when the value is xterm-256color then the application knows it can output color.

I tried setting that env before running the command but that didn't worked

Comment: See [isatty(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)

Comment: Every command is individual and they have different options like clang's `-fcolor-diagnostics`. Linux commands can use [isatty(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html). Windows commands just use `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` and the OS decides if it should color output. Your program is unable to control it for 3rd programs.

Comment: @273K but how is possible that running in a normal terminal the program knows it has to output color then? Can't I just reproduce that?

Comment: The properties that distinguish a terminal from a pipe can't be faked. You are out of luck. You only hope is that the command has options that override the auto-detection. But that won't be the end of the story, because there are different kinds of terminals that your program that prints the output must also understand.